# javascript Function string.slice

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to do this following javascript exercise here:
Create a function called mixUp. It should take in two strings, and return the concatenation of the two strings (separated by a space) slicing out and swapping the first 2 characters of each. You can assume that the strings are at least 2 characters long.

and here's my code:

```
var mixUP = function(a, b) {
  var sliceA = a.slice(0,2);
  var sliceAa = a.slice(2);
  var sliceB = b.slice(0,2);
  var sliceBb = b.slice(2);
  var string = sliceA + sliceBb + " " + sliceB + sliceAa;
  console.log(string);
};
mixUp(apple, pear);
```

Could anyone please help me out here coz it's not working for me. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Add quotes around strings: `mixUp('apple', 'pear');`

Comment: Are apple and pear strings? I don't see quotes and I don't see their definition.

Comment: Last character of MixUp shall be small in the definition...

Comment: @Redu Great catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `mixUP` call it, not `mixUp` last `p` is uppercase.

When you use strings, you need to add quotes around them:

```
var mixUp = function  (a, b) {
    var sliceA = a.slice(0, 2);
    var sliceAa = a.slice(2);
    var sliceB = b.slice(0, 2);
    var sliceBb = b.slice(2);
    var string = sliceA + sliceBb + " " + sliceB + sliceAa;
    console.log(string);
};
mixUp('apple', 'pear');
```

**OUTPUT**

`apar peple`

Answer (score 1):

The way I approached it was:

```
    function mixUp(stringA, stringB) {
        var sliceA = stringA.slice(0,2),
          sliceB = stringB.slice(0,2);
        return (sliceB + stringA.substring(2) + " " + sliceA +
          stringB.substring(2));
    }
```

Which gives you the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Either change the function calling or the function definition to same name as you have taken different names for both.

```js
  var mixUP = function(a, b) {
      var sliceA = a.slice(0,2);
      var sliceAa = a.slice(2);
      var sliceB = b.slice(0,2);
      var sliceBb = b.slice(2);
      var string = sliceA + sliceBb + " " + sliceB + sliceAa;
      console.log(string);
    };
    mixUP("apple", "pear"); // apar peple
```

Comment: `apple` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Typo's:

```
mixUp(apple, pear);
```

should be:

```
mixUP('apple', 'pear');
    ^ ^     ^  ^    ^
```

You called `mixUp` instead of `mixUP`, and both `apple` and `pear` should be strings (Unless they are variables already)

That'll give you the desired result:

```js
var mixUP = function(a, b) {
  var sliceA = a.slice(0,2);
  var sliceAa = a.slice(2);
  var sliceB = b.slice(0,2);
  var sliceBb = b.slice(2);
  var string = sliceA + sliceBb + " " + sliceB + sliceAa;
  console.log(string);
};

mixUP('apple', 'pear');
```